# Running Spring MVC using embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot in Eclipse/STS

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-mvc, embedded-tomcat-8

I am using STS to develop a Spring MVC project with Spring Boot, and I am not able to use the embedded Tomcat to run the project; specifically, the embedded Tomcat is not able to find the JSP page to deliver. But when I deploy it in an independent Tomcat, I have no problem. Here is what I have in application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

And here is where I have put the JSP page:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp
```

And this is what my gradle.build looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'
group = 'com.hua'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
repositories {
  maven {
    credentials {
      username "${artifactory_user}"
      password "${artifactory_password}"
    }
    url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"+'/maven_deploy_virtual'
  }
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I think most likely I need to somehow tell STS where to find the JSP pages when I try to use the embedded Tomcat to run it. But I am not sure how to do that. Can someone give me some guidance? Thanks so much!

Comment: Is your application running if you execute the executable jar?

Comment: No. The jar does not contain WEB-INF. So I can't run it independently.